# how to add sticky footer like clickable image on particular page in webview

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to android.I have created the web view .I like to add footer like clickable image of "click here to purchase" at the bottom.but this should appear on as particular page.and hide on other pages.is there any way of doing this functionality?
your favorable reply is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

set visibility "gone " in your layout that you want appear/disappear.

set visibility to "visible " pragmatically when you want to visible this view.. check my xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what is happening your case is that the webview is occupying some content and that image is also occupying.I want the button-footer strip should over the webview in some cases of webview page.so that i can give some event on that.after clicking on it it should disappear and go on another page of webview.